# Jscrollpane pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, jscrollpane

Well im new to jscrollpane but ive been doing well so far until i placed multiple Mysql Results within a small div and a pagination class.

The scrollbar apears the first time, but as soon as i click page 2, and get the new rows the scrollbar wont appear, this is the pagination method

```
$('#pagination a').click(function(){    
    $.getJSON($(this).attr('href')+'&isajax=true', function(json){          
        $('#mytableinfo').html(json.datos);         
        }
    );
```

so after that i need to reinitialise my jscrollpane so i try to do this as provided by jscrollpane documentation.

```
  var pane = $('.scroll-class')

    var api = pane.data('jsp');
      api.reinitialise();
```

and i cant see anything the scrollbar just wont appear and its driving me nuts.

if i try to reinitialize after hiding-showing divs it does work , but i wont work after changing the whole div content

Answer (score 1):

Try with the **autoReinitialise** parameter:

```
$('.scroll-class').jScrollPane({ showArrows: true, autoReinitialise: true }
```